# How do I surface ASP.NET MVC 2 applications through Websphere Portal 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, websphere, portal

I know this question sounds like utter madness, but hear me out for a second. We're a mixed language shop that has a lot of ASP.NET MVC 2 applications in production. We've no interest in rewriting those applications in another language. That said, we're also a huge  IBM/Notes shop. We plan to make the move to Websphere Portal 7. Most of our Lotus Notes applications will obviously integrate pretty smoothly; however, we're wondering if we can surface our .Net applications through the portal. I've used the IFrame portlet on a page and just pointed the url to the location of a few of our .Net applications. It appears that the application loads, allows for file downloads as it should, can still detect Active Directory, and even the jquery we're using to trigger the auto-save in the background works just it should.

My question: is there a better way to do this? I know it's not ideal.

Another question along these same lines is: do you know of a more robust IFrame portlet that will let you set the width and height of the portlet or will dynamically re-size itself based on the contents it's loading?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Web Application Bridge, which might be the best solution for existing applications. For new development, I would recommend wsrp with netunity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Iframe to display the links of the existing .NET application.
So there wont be any need to re write the entire code.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can use `WSRP` to do this.  NetUnity is one option. MS apparently has one as well.  Would love to hear how it goes.